# In R: FME/ deSolve - SIR fitting (time varying parameters)

Tags: r, parameters, ode, data-fitting, model-fitting

**What I am trying to do:** I have a simple SIR model, with time varying transmission rates beta, I have already implemented this in R (thanks to @tpetzoldt). We have a population of N=10000, gamma is also fixed.

```
  sir_1 <- function(f_beta, S0, I0, R0, times) {

  # the differential equations
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
  beta  <- f_beta(time)
  gamma <- f_gamma(time)
  with(as.list(variables), {
  dS <- -beta * I * S/10000
  dI <-  beta * I * S/10000 - 1/5 * I
  dR <-  1/5 * I
  return(list(c(dS, dI, dR), beta=beta))
  })
  }

# time dependent parameter functions
parameters_values <- list(
f_beta  = f_beta
)

# the initial values of variables
initial_values <- c(S = S0, I = I0, R = R0)



out <- ode(initial_values, times, sir_equations, parameters)
}

times <- seq(0, 19)


f_beta <- approxfun(x=times, y=seq(0.901, 0.92, by=0.001), rule=2)


out <- as.data.frame(sir_1(f_beta=f_beta, S0 = 9990, I0 = 10, R0 = 0, times = times))
```

**Now I have some "real" data, with the FME package I want to get the optimal beta parameters at each timestep**

```
 datareal <- cbind(time = times, I=c(10,32,120,230,480,567,1040,1743,2300,2619,3542,4039,4231,6378, 
 5356, 4987, 3421, 2789, 1789,1156))



 sir_cost <- function (f_beta) {
 outsir <- as.data.frame(sir_1(f_beta=f_beta,  S0 = 9990,  I0 = 10, R0 = 0, times = times))
 costf <- modCost(model = outsir, obs = datareal)
 }


p <- rep(0.8, 20)
Fit <- modFit(f = sir_cost, p = p)

Fit
$par
[1] 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8
```

My issues:

1. For the initial values I took 0.8 at each timestep, however the Fit function does **nothing**, it only returns the 0.8 for each timestep (even if I take a very high value like 800, it says that this is already the best fit). My guess is for timevarying values of the same variable (beta) I have to approach this another way as it is in the documentation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I must say that I expected this follow-up, but I don't think that it is a good idea, because the model is now heavily over-parameterized. FME (and other optimizer packages) can handle this technically, but will not converge due to singularity. If you really want adaptive parameters, try a smooth function.

Comment: @tpetzoldt: thank you so much for checking on this question, could you give me an advice how I could implement it with a smooth function? so I should smooth the beta s at first ? but how can I do the calibration?

Comment: I posted a technical example and some explanations. Instead of `approxfun`, you can use any function, e.g. a polynomial or a `spline` function. The number of fitted parameters should, in general, be smaller than the number of data points.

Comment: A new version of the solution with a spline function was added. It fits both, time dependent beta and gamma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that estimating beta per time step is a good idea. This is inherent in the problem and not a fault of **deSolve** or **FME**. If a dynamic model shall be used to estimate time dependent parameters, I would recommend to use a suitable function with less knots, e.g. time dependent linear, quadratic or spline, for example 3-5 instead of 20 knots. Then replace `approxfun` with that function and plug it in. Model fitting is an art, so play with start values and solvers. And, read the books.

Note that the following is just a **technical demonstration**:

```r
library("deSolve")
library("FME")

sir_1 <- function(f_beta, S0, I0, R0, times) {
  # the differential equations
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
    beta  <- parameters$f_beta(time)
    with(as.list(variables), {
      dS <- -beta * I * S/10000
      dI <-  beta * I * S/10000 - 1/5 * I
      dR <-  1/5 * I
      return(list(c(dS, dI, dR), beta=beta))
    })
  }

  initial_values <- c(S = S0, I = I0, R = R0)
  parameters <- list(f_beta=f_beta)
  out <- ode(initial_values, times, sir_equations, parameters)
}

times <- seq(0, 19)
# use method "constant" to leave beta constant over time step
f_beta <- approxfun(x=times, y=seq(0.901, 0.92, by=0.001), method="constant", rule=2)
out <- sir_1(f_beta=f_beta, S0 = 9990, I0 = 10, R0 = 0, times = times)
plot(out)

datareal <- cbind(time = times, I=c(10,32,120,230,480,567,1040,1743,2300,2619,3542,4039,4231,6378,
                                    5356, 4987, 3421, 2789, 1789,1156))
plot(out, obs=datareal)

sir_cost <- function (p) {
  f_beta <- approxfun(x=times, y=p, method="constant", rule=2)
  outsir <- sir_1(f_beta=f_beta,  S0 = 9990,  I0 = 10, R0 = 0, times = times)
  modCost(model = outsir, obs = datareal)
}

# Play with start values!!!
p <- rep(0.8, 20)

# e.g.: consider random start values
set.seed(123)
p <- runif(20, min=0.8, max=1.2)


# try other solvers, especially such with true box constraints
Fit <- modFit(f = sir_cost, p = p, 
              lower=rep(0.2, 20), upper=rep(5, 20), # box constraints
              method="Port")
summary(Fit) # system is singular (that is what we expected)

# use another solver. Note: it takes a while
Fit <- modFit(f = sir_cost, p = p, 
              lower=rep(0.2, 20), upper=rep(5, 20), # box constraints
              method="L-BFGS-B")

# goes in a surprisingly good direction
Fit$par

f_beta <- approxfun(x=times, y=Fit$par, method="constant", rule=2)
out2 <- sir_1(f_beta=f_beta,  S0 = 9990,  I0 = 10, R0 = 0, times = times)

# compare with data
plot(out, out2, obs=datareal)

# but see how unstable beta is
plot(out2)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Fitting a model with time dependent parameters may be a good idea or not, but if there are reasons to do so, I would suggest to restrict the number of parameters and to use a kind of smooth function.

The following example shows how to use a spline for this purpose, but it is of course also possible (and may be preferable) to use a function with some mechanistic meaning.

As a side effect, it was also possible to identify gamma instead of fixing it a-priori. Nevertheless, this is still a technical demonstration, but I leave the scientific question open, whether a time-dependent beta will make any sense.

```
library("FME")

sir_1 <- function(f_beta, gamma, S0, I0, R0, times) {
  # the differential equations
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
    beta  <- parameters$f_beta(time)
    gamma <- parameters$gamma
    with(as.list(variables), {
      dS <- -beta * I * S / 10000
      dI <-  beta * I * S / 10000 - gamma * I
      dR <-  gamma * I
      # return vector of derivatives, and beta as auxiliary variable
      return(list(c(dS, dI, dR), beta = beta))
    })
  }

  initial_values <- c(S = S0, I = I0, R = R0)
  # pass constant parameter and parameter function together as a list
  parameters <- list(
    f_beta = f_beta,
    gamma  = gamma
  )
  ode(initial_values, times, sir_equations, parameters)
}

times <- seq(0, 19)
datareal <- data.frame(
  time = times,
  I    = c(10, 32, 120, 230, 480, 567, 1040, 1743, 2300,
           2619, 3542, 4039, 4231, 6378,
           5356, 4987, 3421, 2789, 1789, 1156)
)

## define parameter as a vector: gamma and beta
t_beta <- c(0, 12, 16,  19)      #  consider more or less knots
n_beta <- length(t_beta)
y_beta <- rep(1, n_beta)
p      <- c(gamma = 1/5, y_beta) # combine all parameters in one vector

## a small helper function for parameter selection
select <- function(p, which, exclude = FALSE) {
  parnames <- names(p)
  p[(which == parnames) != exclude]
}

## check the helper function
select(p, "gamma")
select(p, "gamma", excl=TRUE)

## cost function, see ?modCost help page
sir_cost <- function (p) {
  gamma   <- select(p, "gamma")
  y_beta  <- select(p, "gamma", exclude = TRUE)
  f_beta  <- splinefun(x = t_beta, y = y_beta)
  outsir  <- sir_1(f_beta = f_beta, gamma = gamma,
                   S0 = 9990,  I0 = 10, R0 = 0, times = times)
  modCost(model = outsir, obs = datareal)
}

## model calibration, see ?modFit
Fit <- modFit(f = sir_cost, p = p,
              # lower bound to avoid negative values of beta
              lower = c(gamma = 0, rep(0.0, n_beta)),
              # note: high sensitivity wrt. upper bound
              upper = c(gamma=1, rep(2.0, n_beta)),
              # an algorithm that supports box constraints
              method = "Port")

## all parameters were identifiable
summary(Fit)

## smaller time steps to obtain a curves
times <- seq(0, 19, 0.1)

## split components of fitted parameters
gamma  <- select(Fit$par, "gamma")
y_beta <- select(Fit$par, "gamma", exclude = TRUE)

out2 <- sir_1(f_beta = splinefun(x = t_beta, y = y_beta), gamma,
              S0 = 9990,  I0 = 10, R0 = 0, times = times)

## show fitted curves and compare simulation with data
## see ?plot.deSolve help page
plot(out2, obs = datareal, which = c("S", "R", "I", "beta"),
     las = 1, obspar = list(pch = 16, col = "red"))
```

[image: comparison of model and data]

Comment: Dear Prof Petzoldt, I can not thank you enough for your time and help and your great packages for R. I have not tried out the new approach with a smooth spline, but I tried the other one on a much larger dataset and it worked perfectly. I will try the one  right now. Thanks again and I wish you all the best